# CSS File Not Load In Maven Project

Tags: java, css, maven, spring-mvc, jsp

My Maven Project Structure is Like Below.I want To Load Css In mainMenu.jsp File.

[image: Folder Structure]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Main.css">
```

Above Line Is Not Working.So How Can I Load Main.css in mainMenu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have Solved Issue By Adding Below Line OF Code In Web Configuraion And Add All Front End File In resources Folder.

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse your WEB-INF layout with what the browser sees. Move your Main.css to "webapp" (or, more commonly "webapp/style"), and then reference it as "Main.css" (if in webapp) or "style/Main.css" (if in webapp/style).

Under WEB-INF, you typically only want files which are processed server-side, eg. JSP (when using a ViewRenderer) or web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot automatically adds static resources located within any of the following directories as mentioned [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot):

> /META-INF/resources/
>   /resources/
>   /static/
>   /public/

Hence, the mistake you are making is by placing static content in wrong directory.